# How to delete package in android?

Tags: android, package

**my application package name like this :**

```
com 
  example 
      developer 
           myproject
```

**and I want to change it like this :**

```
com 
  fyk
    myproject
```

how can I do this ? Any advice or tutorial please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Rename Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)

Comment: Here is Answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092698/8448886

Comment: Go to Manifest, Select the Packge name seperated by dots(.) , right click refactor enter a new name and continue. As simple As this.

Or in Gradle you can give any name you want to package, irrespective of Package created in Project folders

Answer (score 0):

Rename example to fyk.
Then shift all the java files of my project to fyk.
Delete My Project
Now rename the developer to My Project

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the package and use rename option from refactor option. It will refactor all other class in that package automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Android Studio, but if you use Eclipse, it can be done quite simply:

1. Select the package you want to change
2. Press F2
3. Enter the new package name

Or create a new package and copy the files from the old one to the new one

Answer (score 0):

In Android studio top of project structure small **gear icon**(options menu) available click it and uncheck **compact empty middle packages** now your project package folder structure will be broken up. now you can rename it easily